# if a map is bijective, then it has inverse. is the inverse also bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I asked this question because I want to know if given two groups that are isomorphic will always have the same order or not.

Comment: The correct definition of "bijective" is "has an inverse." And the inverse of an inverse is an inverse.

Comment: It is very necessary that if $\phi : G \to G'$ then $|G|=|G'|$. However, this is not sufficient since $|\text{Klein-4}|=|\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}|=4$, but they aren't isomorphic.

Comment: I thought that if it's bijective, then it's also surjective (onto) and injective (one to one) as well.

Comment: so we can generally say that if two groups are isomorphic they will always have the same order but the converse is not always true?

Comment: @Rod Isn't the Klein four-group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$? Did you mean to say $\Bbb{Z}_4$ and $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @Nick: Yeah you're right. I tried to edit, but it was a few minutes too late.

Comment: @Rod:  
so we can generally say that if two groups are isomorphic they will always have the same order but the converse is not always true?

Comment: @jevie The answer to the question in your last comment is yes.